# Hibernate Migration from 4.3.x to 5.x for method org.hibernate.cache.spi.GeneralDataRegion.get(Object key)

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, hibernate-5.x

In Hibernate 4.3.x, there is a method

`org.hibernate.cache.spi.GeneralDataRegion.get(Object key)`

But in Hibernate 5.x, this method signature is changed to

`org.hibernate.cache.spi.GeneralDataRegion.get(SessionImplementor session, Object key)`

Similarly new put method signature in Hibernate-5 is as follows :

```
public void put(SessionImplementor session, Object key, Object value)
```

Here what is SessionImplementor class and how to get its object?
i.e., What will be the code substitution in Hibernate-5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think following line gives SessionImplementor object:

```
SessionImplementor hibernateSession=((SessionImplementor)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
```